# Passing a hidden field based on the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I pass a hidden_field depending on the button clicked?

I have multiple payment methods, stripe and paypal.  I would like to pass a parameter based on which method is used for data and ease of creating the payment.

**For instance if:**

```
<input type="submit" class="a"></input>
```

Is submitted, I want `order.payment_method = a`

**If:**

```
<%= form.submit, id: "b" %>
```

Is submitted, I want `order.payment_method = b`

Is there a rails only way to do this?

I will also be tagging javascript in case

Comment: Why don't you make it a radio select and style the items as buttons? There's probably already a belongs_to relation between payment and payment_method right? Otherwise, that would be the first thing I'd build.

Comment: Or if you don't want to have a separate model (I don't see why you shouldn't in this case though), check out enum: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use input field of type hidden to pass any parameter value. For example

```
<input type="hidden" id="paypal" name="paypalPayment" value="paypal">
```

Hope this helps.
For rails, maybe below link can help
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field

Comment: Unfortunately, "value" is already taken in the input and there doesn't seem to be a way around it because the value displays the words for the button, I'm trying to get a workaround but can't figure out how to display words on the button another way.

Comment: Alright. Then use javascript to add the value when it is clicked. In one of my web apps, i have used like <input type="hidden" id="chosenBy" /> and then using jQuery, i set the value $("#chosenBy").val("someone")

Answer (score 0):

Used JS to solvve:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" %>" name="paypal" onclick= "return handleClick('paypal')"></input>

function handleClick(val){
    document.getElementById('hiddenMethod').value = val;
}
```

Works a bit different with rails/ruby syntax but the gist is there.  Got it working for both fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra hidden input. A submit button itself can pass a value like any other input when you submit the form. If you have a few submit buttons in the form, only the clicked one will be passed.

Each submit button should have a name and a value.

```
<%= form.submit "a", name: "payment_method" %>
<%= form.submit "b", name: "payment_method" %>
```

Also, in your case you should use `button` instead of `submit`. This will allow you to set a button value different from its text.

```
<%= form.button "", value: "a", name: "payment_method", type: "submit" %>
<%= form.button "", value: "b", name: "payment_method", type: "submit" %>
```